# Is there a way to shut of a Middleware in node router.use() method when convenient?

Tags: node.js, express, angular2-routing

So I just came to a problem in my node app where in the back-end I created a login and register post method that takes in username and password. Then I created a middleware `router.use` that use token in browser to get users profile information. The problem is everything bellow that middleware is now requres a token header authentication:

```
this.options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': this.auth.authToken
  })
});
```

I want to know how I can bypass this middleware and not use header authentication to get my blogs that are posted in the database.

Here is the middleware.

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (!token) {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token'
        });
    } else {
        jwt.verify(token, Data.secret, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Token invalid: ' + err
                });
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Every post and get methods bellow this router middleware requires I use this middleware. Is there anyway I can bypass this middleware and not use a requestOptions authentication to get my blogs from database?
Thanks

Comment: The usual solution would be to install the middleware either with a path or in a router so that it ONLY affects the routes you want it to affect. Since you don't show us how your URLs are structure for the routes were you want it in force and the routes that you don't, we can't make a specific recommendation. You could also just have the middleware check the path of the URL in the request and have it decide whether it is supposed to apply its work or not to this URL. This is less of a clean solution vs. installing the middleware so that it only gets called when you want.

Comment: Hey thanks, I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is to register the routes that do *not* need the token above this middleware, and those that do need the token *below* this middleware.  Routes respect registration order.

Alternatively, your logic clearly sends a response if there's no token.  You could also simply *not* do that and allow the future routes to handle the case that there is no token.  It really depends on your use case.